# Iterating through a Dictionary to add to another

Tags: javascript

I am trying to loop through each value in my dictionary and then go out and get another dictionary based on one of the objects in the first dictionary through each loop iteration:

```
var dAlbumPhotos = {};  // holds a list of photo objects
var dAlbumsAndPhotos = {}; // will hold all the album | dAlbumPhotos for each album

for(var a in dAlbums)
{
    dAlbumPhotos = GetPhotosForAlbum(userID, accessToken, a.id);

    dAlbumsAndPhotos(a) = dAlbumPhotos;
}
```

I'm not quite sure how to do this without an index.  I need to increment through the dAlbumPhotos and append to the final dictionary that album and it's dAlbumPhotos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're really using an Associative Array in Javascript so you should be able to change the last bit of your code to be:

```
for(var a in dAlbums)
{
    dAlbumPhotos = GetPhotosForAlbum(userID, accessToken, dAlbums[a].id);
    dAlbumsAndPhotos[a] = dAlbumPhotos;
}
```

Comment: @coffeeaddict - Actually, it's an associative array (which is what all object properties are in Javascript): http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html.

Comment: thanks...did not know this was an associative array...thought that this nvp was something else.

Comment: ok so by doing this dAlbumsAndPhotos[a] = dAlbumPhotos; there is really no "index" to speak of interms of needing to refernce an index for the associative array in order to add each a and dAlbumPhotos pair?

Comment: so all a "dictionary" is in JS is an object with properties....and properties of course are the name/value pairs

Comment: @coffeeaddict - In this case, a is going to be the index (you can use the same for loop structure to loop through dAlbumsAndPhotos as you did through dAlbums).

Comment: crap, so I do really need a dictionary even though I'm not storing a string in the name for each name/value pair.  Because in the end I want a list of name/value pairs stuffed into a return object where it's customObject/array as the name value pairs.  I need sleep badly.

Comment: Ok, I'm wondering if I'm just not even looking at this right.  How do you create collection or dictionary of object / object pairs?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you're after:

```
var dAlbumPhotos = {};  // holds a list of photo objects
var dAlbumsAndPhotos = {}; // will hold all the album | dAlbumPhotos for each album

for(var a in dAlbums)
{
    dAlbumPhotos = GetPhotosForAlbum(userID, accessToken, dAlbums[a]);

    dAlbumsAndPhotos[a] = dAlbumPhotos;
}
```

Comment: ok, yea that first correctly makes sense now.  Just don't understand how the index of dAlbumsAndPhotos is working here or being referenced.

Answer (score 0):

A `for..in` loop gives you back the indexes, not the objects in the loop. That is, `a.id` is likely nonsensical -- you really mean `dAlbums[a].id`. It follows that `dAlbumsAndPhotos[a]` is probably where you need to store the results.

Comment: I'm creating a dictionary that contains name value pairs...so dAlbumsAndPhotos will hold an album object : dictionaryOfPhotoObjects

Comment: I just did not understand how to reference the index for the dAlbumsAndPhotos when trying to add each album and its dictionary of photo pairs

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have the photo data in a json table like this:

```
var dPhotos = [{src: "/photos/a.jpg", album: "animals"}, {src: "/photos/b.jpg", album: "landscapes"}];
```

Then you can use jOrder to extract the group index like this:

```
var table = jOrder(dPhotos)
    .index('album', ['album'], {grouped: true});

var index = table.index('album').flat();
```

This index will hold a dictionary with album names associated with the a list of ids of rows in dPhotos belonging to that album.

jOrder is available from http://github.com/danstocker/jorder